Unable to set HTTP status code for Policy response (Laravel)
I'm building an API with Laravel 10 and the JSON:API library. In this app, one of the main resources (Expense) has a to-one relationship with de User model. I decided to build this application practicing TDD, so one of my firsts tests checks if a user can fetch a resource that belongs to another user. To achieve this, I'm using assertNotFound() to verify that the HTTP response code returned by the server equals 404 Not Found, because I wish not to reveal any resource's existence in these cases.
On the other hand, there is a ExpensePolicy with a view() method that verifies whether the authenticated user is the owner of the resource or not. In case of truth, it simply returns true, but, as I just mentioned, in any other case I would like to get an HTTP 404 Not Found status code, so I'm returning an object calling Response::denyAsNotFound().
Finally, the ExpenseController has no method defined yet, it's working with the default behaviour.
So, the problem here is: I'm stuck trying to get the 404 Not Found status code the test is expecting. It's returning 403 Forbidden status code every time the authorization fails, despite the view() method of the ExpensePolicy returning a Response object with its status attribute equal to 404.
ExpensePolicy.php
namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Expense;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;

class ExpensePolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function view(User $user, Expense $expense)
    {
        return $user->is($expense->user) ?: Response::denyAsNotFound();
    }
}

The test I wrote for this particular case:
public function test_fetching_a_single_expense_fails_if_the_resource_belongs_to_another_user()
{
    $expense = Expense::factory()->for($this->user1)->create();

    $response = $this
        ->actingAs($this->user2)
        ->jsonApi()
        ->expects('expenses')
        ->get(route('v1.expenses.show', $expense));

    $response->assertNotFound();
}

I am sure that the logic inside the view() method of the ExpensePolicy is working, because if I change the else block of the ternary to true, then it will return the resource with a 200 OK status code, even though it does not belong to the user. In the same way, if I change that else block to false, it will return 403 Forbidden code again; and if use $this->user1 as argument for actingAs() when making the request, it will successfully return the resource too as the authenticated user is the owner of the expense.
According to what I understand on Laravel's documentation about this topic, it should work correctly.
I found this question from user @IharAliakseyenka and this possible solution that user @geertjanknapen linked in one of the comments, but I keep wondering why would the official documentation provide wrong or unuseful information about a method whose purpose seems to be very clear to me.
Is there some step I'm skipping? Am I misunderstanding the documentation? Please, let me know if I can share some other code fragments of interest with you.
Sorry if my English is not very accurate. I'd really appreciate your help on solving this issue.
Thank you in advance.

The null coalescing operator ?? means "if the left hand side is null or not defined then use what's on the right".  $user->is($expense->user) appears to return a boolean value  so even if that is false it will not be null. I think you need $user->is($expense->user) ?: Response::denyAsNotFound() (note the ?: which is a shorthand ternary)

@apokryfos thank you very much, I made that mistake when editing the post, in fact I'm using ?: in the code. I have edited and reviewed the post just in case there was some other error. Sorry, publishing too late at nigth :S
